# how do I make specific content display in an append function?

Tags: javascript, html

first of all i would like to state that i am working in jquery mobile.

basically i have the following code below:

```
if($("#favourite1").is(":checked")){
    $("#favouritecontent").append("");
}
```

now in the append function i would like to display the following code below or something along those lines:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
        <img src="chrome.png">
        <h2>Google Chrome</h2>
        <p>Google Chrome is a free, open-source web browser. Released in 2008.</p>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

any ideas how i would do it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
const html = `
    <ul data-role="listview">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
        <img src="chrome.png">
        <h2>Google Chrome</h2>
        <p>Google Chrome is a free, open-source web browser. Released in 2008.</p>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

`

```
if ($("#favourite1").is(":checked")){
   $("#favouritecontent").append(html);
}
```

Comment: Yeah it works...you just have to tie it to some event. Checkout https://jsfiddle.net/v33zy2rt/